# android-display multiple images and to next line if no enough room

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know if this is possible....the idea is just like `TextView`. text would go to next line if there is no enough room to display all. but instead of plain text, I want to do images. Lets say I want to display a random number of smiling face. can be 0 to 100. what I can think of now is having a `LinearLayout`, and just dynamically create `ImageView` then add it to the `LinearLayout`. depending on the orientation of the `LinearLayout` I ended up of having a row/column of partial smiling faces. even if I had a `ScrollView`, I'm able to see all the smiling faces but just in one row/column.

is there a way that I can dynamically load the next smiling face to the new line if there's no enough room?

Comment: Are the pictures all of the same size? The simplest way I can think of is using a GridView, and set the column width to the size of the pictures (but all the pictures must be of the same size)

Comment: not the same size. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate a gridview and it'll automatically send images into the next row/column if they dont fit.

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"/>
```

Comment: but gridview acts like a listview. instead of wrapping the content height like textview, gridview gives you a scrollbar

Comment: thats exactly what the 'android:numColumns="auto_fit"' is for.

Comment: after several tries, i still wasn't able to get what i need. auto_fit always gives me just two images in a row for some reason. but thanks for the help, i'll keep trying and see if i can manage to get something positive.

Comment: use: android:columnWidth, android:horizontalSpacing, android:verticalSpacing. Ive used gridview with more than 2 colums several times.